# Snapping with 'median' part has a bug in 2.80?

Tags: snapping

[image]

I know that snapping with 'median' option works like above picture.

But  it works differently  in Blender 2.80 like below picture.

[image]

Is snapping  buggy in 2.80?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe its something not visible on your setting. Could you save the file, try to see if it is happening again if you reopen it and if yes upload it here so that we could check.

Comment: @lemon I don't know how to upload a file here

Comment: Use this link, grab your file in it, accept and paste the url of your question https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ You will obtain a html to paste in your question

Comment: @lemon [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6389" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6389/)

Comment: Same here with your file. Strangely if you do it with the other cube the behavior is still not good but different.

Comment: @lemon Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't know (we are not linked to blender coders here). Do you remember how you came to have this issue? I mean just open blender duplicate the cube and try to snap or was it another way?

Comment: OK... this is a bug. Works only is the object we want to snap has its origin at the center of the world.

Comment: FYI https://developer.blender.org/T68684

Comment: @lemon thank you for your effort. have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: seems to be a bug effectively. Snapping with median target works only if the object origin is at the center of the world. If not, there is a delta which correspond to the delta between its origin and the world center.

So the following is true **only** if the edited object is at center:

---

This is not a bug, but an enhancement.

In 2.8 you can specify what will be snap (vertex, edge, etc.) and that has an influence on what is considered as snap target.

So you can snap *vertices* (with median) and that will stuck to the target *vertices*.

[image]

Or you can snap *edges* and that will stuck to the target *edges*.

[image]

Comment: In your gif median point of selected vertices touches target point. But in my case (as shown in 2nd picture) median point did not touch target point. I don't know why this happen to me. I have a formal 2.80 version. It's really strange..

Comment: OK, I see now, thanks for the gif add.

Comment: Do I have a wrong 2.80 version?

Comment: @나미손, try to type 'bpy.app.version_string' in the Python console, you should have '2.80 (sub 75)'.

Comment: I did it and added a picture

Comment: Using recent release build, sub75,  Win64.. I think this is a bug .. works as expected with the 'Center' option, which in this case, should be identical. Is the translation component of the source-object's Xform being ignored, or something like that?

Comment: @lemon I added a gif including whole process.